# How to create pdf file with layout applied to it. Using pdfkit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit, render-to-string

```
require 'pdfkit'
html = render_to_string(:layout => 'layouts/test_layout' , :action => print_form.html.erb")
kit = PDFKit.new(html)
send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "Form.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf')
```

above code generates PDF file without layout specified. How do I create PDF file with layout applied.

```
layouts/test_layout ->   test.css, test.js
```

My test_layout contains some JavaScript and CSS files.

Please suggest me, I want to print form in PDF format with specified layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your `render_to_string` method we can't tell what's going wrong. Here is example code for generating a pdf with layout: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#usage

Comment: Am providing my Html form to render_to_string method which is "print_form.html.erb" which contain layout "test_layout"

Comment: render_to_string is a Rails method. I guess the OP didn't override it.